# how to add textbox in spring using jquery

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

### Spring MVC

I have doing following code to add text box in spring MVC form. I have used jquery to add text box dynamically in spring form. But when i am trying to add spring text box this code odes not work.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ page session="false"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
div {
    padding: 8px;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var counter = 2;
        $("#addButton").click(function() {
          if        (counter > 10) 
         {
                                                      alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
                                                return false;
                                            }

                                            var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
                                                                .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv'+ counter);
                                            newTextBoxDiv.append('<label>Input Title '+ counter
                                                                    + ' : </label>'
                                                                    + '<form:input path="labels[2]" id="textbox' + counter + '" />');

                                            newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxDiv"+ counter);
                                            counter++; 
                                            $("#TextBoxesGroup").append(newTextBoxDiv);

                        });//addButton close

                        // remove textbox
                        $("#removeButton").click(function() {
                            if (counter == 1) {
                                alert("No more textbox to remove");
                                return false;
                            }
                            counter--;
                            $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();
                        });// end remove textbox

                        // get textbox value
                        $("#getButtonValue").click(
                                function() {

                                    var msg = '';
                                    for (i = 1; i < counter; i++) {
                                        msg += "\n Textbox #" + i + " : "
                                                + $('#textbox' + i).val();
                                    }
                                    alert(msg);
                                });
                    }); // end get textbox value
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form:form method="POST" commandName="subindicator" action="saveXML">
        <div>
    <div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
        <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
            <label>Input Title 1 : </label><form:input path="labels[1]" id='textbox1'/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type='button' value='Add Button' id='addButton'>
    <input type='button' value='Remove Button' id='removeButton'>
    <input type='button' value='Get TextBox Value' id='getButtonValue'>

    </div>
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

This code works for html text box but not work to add spring text box and does not work for:

```
newTextBoxDiv.append('<label>Input Title '+ counter
                                                                    + ' : </label>'
                                                                    + '<form:input path="labels[2]" id="textbox' + counter + '" />');
```

Above code work if i write this code in such a way-

```
var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
         .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

    newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Textbox #'+ counter + ' : </label>' +
          '<input type="text" name="textbox' + counter + 
          '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >');
```

Please provide me solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened because,

```
<form:input path="labels[2]" id="textbox' + counter + '" />
```

will be converted to,

```
<input name"labels[2]" id="labels2">
```

and javascript can't understand the spring form tags. whenever you click the add button you can use the incremented counter value to generate new index just the way you are now doing.